# Selenium Webdriver UnknownError: performActions (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, jquery-ui, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, jquery-ui-slider

**Update**

I've since replicated the problem in a simpler way.

The HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="../../../libs/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="abc" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:green;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $("#abc").on('click', function() {
    alert('clicked');
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The Ruby:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
options = {}
options[:profile] = profile
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, options
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10

driver.navigate.to("the_above_html_file")
driver.action.move_to(driver.find_element(:id, "abc")).click.perform
```

When the Ruby runs the JavaScript alert is not opened as expected; instead Ruby generates this stack trace:

```
"performActions"
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok': performActions (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:32:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:83:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:83:in `create_response'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:107:in `request'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:61:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:640:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:417:in `send_actions'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/w3c_action_builder.rb:164:in `perform'
    from finder/tests/automated/test.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

Why does this fail?  Targeting the element with `driver.find_element(:id, "id").click` works as expected so it seems to be related to the `action` classes.

Running Ruby 2.2.5 with Webdriver 3.4.0 and GeckoDriver 0.16.1.

**Original Post - No Longer Relevant**

Running Ruby 2.2.5 with Webdriver 3.4.0 and GeckoDriver 0.16.1.

An acceptance test is doing:

```
element = @driver.find_element(:class, "ui-slider-handle")
@driver.action.drag_and_drop_by(element, 50, 0).perform
```

Where `element` is the moveable slider created by jQuery UI Sliders - see https://jqueryui.com/slider/.  We are using version `jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js`.

The slider works correctly when I use it manually but the acceptance test throws:

```
TestDistanceSlider#test_store_container_and_markers_updated_when_slider_moved:
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: performActions
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:32:in `initialize'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:83:in `new'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:83:in `create_response'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:107:in `request'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:61:in `call'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:640:in `execute'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:417:in `send_actions'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/w3c_action_builder.rb:164:in `perform'
    tests/automated/test_distance_slider.rb:18:in `_move_slider_by_percent'
    tests/automated/test_distance_slider.rb:24:in `_move_slider_to_top'
    tests/automated/test_distance_slider.rb:139:in `test_store_container_and_markers_updated_when_slider_moved'
```

How can we diagnose the cause of the `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: performActions` that is thrown?

We have tried this workaround but it gives the same error:

```
 @driver.action.click_and_hold(element).move_by(100, 0).release.perform
```

Comment: Hi, When you decide to use Ruby Selenium Binding, why don't you use WATIR, WATIR is the good wrapper around Ruby Selenium Binding. Many extra features added.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess would be that you are using some older version of geckodriver because actions class was buggy and has been recently implemented.

I tried your example and it worked like a charm. Here is a screenshot of it.  [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/fGZxSa) .

Specs :
Firefox : 53.0.4
Geckodriver : 0.16.1
selenium-webdriver : 3.4.0

Let me know if it worked with latest versions.
Hope it helps!!